# How2: Set different styles based on multilevel list promotion

Tags: ms-word

In using a multi-level list, I want 14 pt.s, bold at the highest promotion level (“1”).
Then, for lower levels (“1.1,” “1.1.1,” etc.), I want 12 pt.s, *not* bold.  Additionally, I want to establish the indentation the same way, so that merely demoting/promoting an item will affect its indentation in ways I have specified.

How do I set up styles, or a style, so that merely changing the promotion of an item will cause it to inherit the style for that level?